# conditional markup display

Tags: channel-entries, channel, loop

I've got a CSS module that I only want to display on the page if there are entries in the channel.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="staff" dynamic="no" limit="6" orderby="random" {gv_param_disable_default}}

{!-- don't want this part to loop but should only display once if entries exist --}
<section id="staff-module">
    <h2>Meet the staff</h2>
    <div id="staff-photies">

        {!-- this is the part we want to loop --}
        <a href="/about/meet-the-staff/">
            <figure>

                {exp:ce_img:single src="{cf_people_photo}" width="140" crop="yes" alt="{title}"}
                <figcaption>{title}</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </a>
{if count == total_results}
    </div>

</section>
<!-- // staff-module -->
{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Am I missing something blatantly obvious in my conditional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I was missing something obvious.

```
{if count == "1"}
<section id="staff-module">
<h2>Meet the staff</h2>
<div id="staff-photies">
{/if}
```